# Скрипт кнопки Restart работает некорректно. Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Есть button, на котором висит пустой объект, а на объекте скрипт, по сути этот скрипт должен включать отображение button при уничтожении игрока, но он этого не делает, предполагаю что некорректно реализовал условие if

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject _player;

private void Start()
{
    transform.parent.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

private void Update()
{
    if(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player") == null)
    {
        transform.parent.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
public void OnClick()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}
```

Comment: `Update()` с большой буквы.

Comment: @aepot подобные ошибки появились только потому, что я вручную все возвращал к первому варианту написания, так что не беспокойтесь, даже если написать с большой - не поможет

Comment: Так исправьте..

Comment: @aepot ладно, исправил, надеюсь теперь вы, ну или же кто то другой, сможет лучше разобраться в проблеме

Comment: Какое-то у вас странное условие... Есть переменная _player, но она никак не используется. Может планировалось `(_player == null)`?

Comment: @МаксимФисман да, так и планировалось, но это не сработало, т.к. объект, оказывается, не удаляется в менеджере(или инспекторе, не знаю как правильно назвать), а про переменную просто забыл

Comment: Если он не удаляется, то и условие работать не будет, нужно другое условие смерти игрока

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, напишу вариант решения для таких же гениев как и я, у которых возникла подобная проблема

суть проблемы была в том, что при отключении объекта button, отключался и сам скрипт, то есть все переставало работать, я решил эту проблему подобными строками:

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject _restarter;//сюда нужно поместить кнопку рестарта, или что там у вас 

 public void Destroyer() 
{
    Player.transform.Translate(0, -10, 0);
    _restarter.SetActive(true);
} // весь этот скрипт был один целым, из-за этого если я уничтожал объект, то все равно ничего не работало, поэтому если player достигал 0 хп, то он перемещался куда то, также по дефолту я выключал кнопку, ну и уже в этом методе включал
```

Answer (score 0):

`GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag();` возвращает массив. Если ничего не найдено, то он возвращает массив с длиной 0. Вообще длина этого массива будет показывать количество объектов с этим тэгом на сцене.

Попробуй так:

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject _player;

private void Start()
{
    transform.parent.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

private void Update()
{
    if(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player").Length == 0)
    {
        transform.parent.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
public void OnClick()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}
```

Comment: Вы серьезно предлагает каждый кадр использовать "FindGameObjectsWithTag()"?

Comment: @user:295192 Нет, я просто исправил условие так, что бы оно выполнялось как это задумывалось. Я не претендовал на эффективность этого решения, но претендую на то что оно работает. Как бы вы решили эту задачу? Как говориться критикуешь предлагай.

Comment: @user:295192 я бы наверно реализовал через Скрипт на Игроке c помощью OnDestroy